# There exists (variants)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let us suppose there was a statement:

"A bounded real function cannot be surjective".

Is the negation:

"All bounded real functions can be surjective"?

My reasoning is that "A" translates to "There exists", so by quantifier negation, it would become "For all".

Comment: I would translate "A bounded real function cannot be surjective" as "if a function is bounded, then it is not surjective" or "all bounded functions are not surjective"

Comment: I would say, "No bounded real function is surjective," or "there does exist a surjective, bounded real function."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Statement itself is translated as " For all x, if x is a bounded real function then x is not surjective"

The negation is then "There exists an x such that x is a bounded real function and x is surjective"

Equivalently, "There exists a bounded real function that is surjective".

Answer (score 1):

"A bounded real function cannot be surjective" should be written as "$ \forall f.\neg$ (Bounded_real_function($f$) and surjective($f$))." So the negation of this become $\exists f.$ (Bounded_real_function($f$) and surjective($f$))." Which can be translated to "there exists a surjective bounded real function."

Your mistake is that you translated "A bounded real function cannot be surjective" to "$\exists f.$ (Bounded_real_function($f$) and $\neg$ can_be_surjective($f$))", but this is clearly nonsense: functions don't have the property of "can be surjective", they either are or aren't.